# How to get the input array of city and capital in a javascript file?

Tags: javascript, php

[The Web Page looks like this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzrsb.png). I have two arrays as Input in the code and want to retrieve the contents of the arrays in the showscore() function, I have pasted the code snippets of what I have tried.
The query will give a list of strings which are stored in arr1 and arr2 and are shuffled in the code henceforth. The shuffled arr1 is displayed to the user and a response is input using the form which is then stored in the city array.

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="scripts/getScore.js"></script>
<div id="score">
                <?php
                for ($i = 0; $i < $number; $i = $i + 1) {
                ?>
                    <form id="main">
                        <?php
                        echo $string1 . " " . $state[$i] . " " . $string2 ?>
                        <input type="text" placeholder="Enter answer" name="city[]" required />
                    <?php
                }
                    ?>
                    <input type='hidden' name='capital[]' value="<?php echo json_encode($capital); ?>" />
                    <button type="button" value="Submit" onclick="showscore()">Submit</button>
                    </form>
            </div>
```

The showscore() function inside the getScore.js is:

```
function showscore() {
var request;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    request = new XMLHttpRequest();
}
else {
    request = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
request.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        console.log(this.responseText);
        document.getElementById("score").innerHTML = this.responseText;
    }
};
var myForm = document.forms.main;
var city = mForm.elements['city[]'];
var capital=myForm.elements['capital[]'];
console.log(city);
console.log(capital[0]);
var c =0;
for (var i = 0; i < capital.length; i++) {
    console.log(capital[i]);
    console.log(city[i]);
    if(city[i] == capital[i]){
        c++;
    }
}
console.log("Your Score is "+c);

}
```

Comment: Please click edit, then `[<>]` and create a[mcve] WITHOUT php, only RENDERED HTML and script - this is not a php question

Comment: 1. You cannot have duplicate IDs. 2. You use form.name and not the ID in the script. Change to class and loop over document.querySelectorAll(".formClass")

Comment: Why not JSON encode the cities and the capitals and just use that in the script instead? You can then generate the forms on the client

Comment: Also you need to JSON.parse(capital) or just use it as raw JS object in the script

Comment: @mplungjan how can I encode the cities and also to make it clear the cities are being input by the user and the length of the cities array could be of any length

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. You cannot have duplicate IDs.
2. You use form.name and not the ID in the script. Change to class and loop over document.querySelectorAll(".formClass")
3. Why not JSON encode the cities and the capitals and just use that in the script instead? You can then generate the forms on the client

My suggestion - untested against your arrays because I do not have examples of your cities and capital arrays.

```js
const states = {
  "Odisha": ["Bhubaneswar"],
  "Andhra Pradesh": ["Amaravati", "Hyderabad"]
} // <?php echo json_encode(states); ?>;
const form = document.getElementById("main");
let html = ['<fieldset>']
Object.keys(states).forEach(state => html.push(`<label>What is the capital of ${state}?</label> <input type="text" data-state="${state}" placeholder="Enter answer" name="city[]" required />`));
html.push('<button type="button" id="checkBut">Check</button> <div readonly id="total"></div>')
html.push('</fieldset>')
form.innerHTML = html.join('<hr>')
window.addEventListener("load", function() {
  document.getElementById("checkBut").addEventListener("click", () => {
    let c = 0;
    [...document.querySelectorAll("[name^=city]")].forEach(input => c += states[input.getAttribute("data-state")].indexOf(input.value) !== -1 ? 1 : 0);
    document.getElementById("total").innerText = "Your Score is " + c;
  });
});
```

```css
#score {
  width: 80%
}

fieldset {
  min-width: 500px;
  display: inline-block;
}

fieldset input {
  float: right;
}

#total {
  float: right;
}
```

```html
<div id="score">
  <form id="main">

  </form>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for this solution!
cities array would have inputs from the user like:[Panaji,Gandhinagar,abc,xyz] and the capital array would have the right answers like:[Panaji,Gandhinagar,Shimla,Lucknow] and I have to check both and output the score inside the div.

Comment: And the code snippet 1 I added is a part of another block of code which comprises of php and is supposed to initialize the capital array with the right values.

Comment: I have added some more description and code to make it easy to understand

Comment: You do not seem to answer ANY of my request. I do NOT want to see PHP. I need to see the JSON and the HTML!!!

Comment: Sorry! I have updated the code snippets and this is the full html and js I am writing, the thing I wanna do is check the city[i]==capital[i] calculate the score and display it on my div.

Comment: Your showscore does not actually SEND anything to the PHP - it does not make any sense to have the AJAX in there

Comment: Okay! I am getting you and thank you for bearing with me on this, also if you can suggest me something if not AJAX then how should I fulfil the task I need to do.

Comment: I am. My code is very much close to what you want, but I cannot finish it without seeing an example of your web page and the cities and capital arrays AFTER they are converted to JSON

Comment: Capital:Array ( [0] => Chennai [1] => Shillong )
Cities:Array ( [0] => Bhopal [1] => Bhopal )
Web Page:https://i.stack.imgur.com/gzrsb.png

Comment: I do not want PHP!?!? - please show me the JSON encoded arrays of cities and capitals... please?

Comment: capital:a:2:{i:0;s:7:"Chennai";i:1;s:8:"Shillong";}
and please do have a look I am not encoding the cities array and the way I am doing it If I console.log it is giving me the same array for cities I provided u earlier, cities array contains the input taken from the user

Comment: `capital:a:2:{i:0;s:7:"Chennai";i:1;s:8:"Shillong";}` is not valid JSON

Comment: Please see complete examples. You just need to echo a list of states with their capitals in an array (because of the two capitals of Andhra Pradesh